# Unlimited number of checkboxes

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I wonder how to create mechanism which create new checkbox below previous when you click on button. Number of checkboxes are unlimited.
I don't think that table of objects work well, so I think about implementation in list of objects.
Any suggestions?

Comment: The standard library has both `list` and `vector` classes that can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do:

1. Create an event for clicking that button (let's call it `OnBtnClick`)
2. Use a vector/list to hold all the checkboxes
3. When `OnBtnClick` is called you do:

   - create a checkbox with the desired position and size and make sure it receives an unique id (this will help you differentiate between checkboxes when they are clicked/checked/etc).
   - add the checkbox to the list (to get its status: *checked* or *not checked*)
   - add the checkbox to the desired window, the parent window (though this may happen automatically when you create it)
   - if you want to add an event for the added checkbox you should check the manual of your GUI framework (you will probably use the same event handler for all checkboxes and treat them separately based on their id)

Depending on the GUI framework used the bottom details may vary but the idea remains the same. I did this with wxWidgets, QT and MFC but I don't know which framework you use. You should be able to find code samples for each framework.

Comment: I think about that maybe create 2 tables of objects, on start first table has 1 object, when you add new task second table will redeclarated with size = [old+2], objects from previous table are rewritten to new table, and new task also will be added to this table. 

But this solution isnt optimized.

Answer (score 0):

What would you do with unlimited number of check boxes - confuse the user? So, that he/she wouldn't attempt to use it again? Bad idea, as you can guess now.

You may (should) limit the number of check boxes (or better, limit the number of controls on form/dialog). IMO, more than 10-12 CBs would be cumbersome for the end user. Therefore, better idea is to have **all** of them on dialog/dialog-resource, and make all of them invisible/disabled. When user does some action, make them visible/enabled - so that end user may do something with it.

Still demand N number of CBs, where N is not determined beforehand? Then you may have checkboxes under Combo box, or use check-boxes under List Control. List Control already hosts this feature, but for CBs under Combo, you may need to write your own class.See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/checkcmb.aspx) as an example.

Comment: I want to create interface which user can add unimited number of tasks for my program. For example: you can create a file (with unique name) and delete it, unlimited number of times. In interface i want to create bunton which create new task - checkbox, textlabel etc., where you can specyfiy what you want to do (delete, rename, create etc.).

Comment: Use list control with check boxes.